# I cannot call a function in another JavaScript file

Tags: 8, javascript

I have two JavaScript files on my custom theme. One file has functions that need to be used on the other file. What I have below doesn't work. This is the error I get.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined.

jQuery will be used on both files.

#### file1.js

```js
/**
 * @file
 * UI behaviors
 */

(function ($, Drupal) {

 'use strict';

  $(document).ready(function () {
    function test(){
     console.log('hello'):
    }
  });

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

#### file2.js

```js
/**
 * @file
 * UI behaviors
 */

(function ($, Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  $(document).ready(function () {
     test();
  });

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

#### customtheme.libraries.yml

```yaml
scripts:
  js:
    js/file1.js: {}
    js/file2.js: {}
```

#### customtheme.info.yml

```yaml
libraries:
 - 'customtheme/scripts'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `test()` is wrapped in an anonymous function, making it not available outside of that function.

I would add it to the Drupal object:

File 1:

```
(function($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.myFunction = function() {
    // Do something.
  }
}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

File 2:

```
(function($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.myFunction();
});
```

Also, as a side note, `$(document).ready()` is not used in Drupal. In Drupal `Drupal.behaviors` is used instead: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview